# Sklean's Pandas error : Error on 1 column of pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am applying scaling on one of the columns of pandas, But it's giving me an error

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, StandardScaler

df:

group people value value_50
  1    5      100    1
  2    2      90     1
  1    10     80     1
  2    20     40     0
  1    7      10     0
  2    23     30     0

df = pd.read_clipboard()
```

selecting one column

```
y_train = df.value
sc = StandardScaler()
y_train_sc = sc.fit_transform(y_train)
y_train_sc = sc.fit_transform(y_train.values)
```

but getting a type error for both the try

```
 ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
```

How to do it with pandas and sklearn?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
y_train_sc = sc.fit_transform(y_train.to_frame())
```

or select as `y_train= df[['value']]`. You are selecting the column as 1D Series when `StandardScaler` expects a 2D DataFrame-like input.